# Google Meet PWA with StartParameters?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest, shortcut, google-meet

I often use Google Meet. I have now installed the PWA in Windows and am trying to open this PWA with a specific link. Code. e.g. "KDF-UZR-DFHK". I want to click on this link and join my meeting immediately. But not with Chrome, but with the PWA. I have tried to pass a "start_url=KDFUZRDFHK" in the settings of the PWA icon. But unfortunately that didn't work.
Is there any way I can intervene in the manifest?

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=kjgfgldnnfoeklkmfkjfagphfepbbdan